# Notepad++: how to save edited file automatically before launching in browser?

Tags: browser, notepad++, application-launch, autosave

I am editing say an HTML file in Notepad++ and want to see the result in a browser launched by a keyboard command defined in the Run menu. The problem is that I always need to press Ctrl+S to save my edits before launching the browser. Is there a way to configure Notepad++ to save the file automatically on the browser launch so that I will only press the keyboard combination to launch the browser?

Comment: Have you tried to create a macro that save the file & launch the browser?

Comment: @Toto, No. Any example how to do that?

Comment: You could find some tips [here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16170/creating-and-running-macros)

Comment: @Toto, I can't find how to run an external app with parameters from a native Notepad++ macro. I need this command to launch the browser with the full path to the current file. Perhaps, we need to use NppExec or something like that to implement what I need.

Comment: @Toto, see my answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented what I need with the NppExec plugin. After installing it, I opened its Execute dialog and wrote the following script:

```
npp_console 0
npp_save
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Then saved it as a macro with the name 'Save and Open in Firefox'. After this I opened the Advanced Options for the NppExec plugin and added my script to the Macros submenu using the corresponding button in the options dialog. And finally, I assigned the ALT+F1 key to this macro using the standard 'Modify Shortcut/Delete Command' dialog in Notepad++ (can be found in the Macro or Run menu).